# How to get 19 pound cat to lose weight

Tags: cats, health, diet, feeding

I need to get my cat to lose wight, she's 4 years old, short hair, and 19 pounds. I currently feed her one cup dry food in the night along with 1/2 cup in the morning and 1 can of wet food every one or two days. How do I get her to lose weight without switching the type of food I get her?